# For $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1$ prove $\frac{1}{ab+2c^{2}+2c}+\frac{1}{bc+2a^{2}+2a}+\frac{1}{ca+2b^{2}+2b}\ge \frac{1}{ab+bc+ca}$

Tags: inequality

For $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=1.$ Prove$:$ $$\frac{1}{ab+2c^{2}+2c}+\frac{1}{bc+2a^{2}+2a}+\frac{1}{ca+2b^{2}+2b}\geqq \frac{1}{ab+bc+ca}$$
well i try to  use AM-GM but turns out:

$$\frac{9}{4(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+5(ab+bc+ca))} \geq\frac1{ab+bc+ca}$$

and i always get this : $$ab+bc+ca \geq a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$$

can someone help me what i'm doing wrong here ?

P/S : this is the first time I use this format so pls anyone can help me edit this , thank you !

Comment: Try to include your attempt to avoid being downvoted. Though I usually don’t downvote.

Comment: Are you sure about the $ab+bc+ca \geq a^2+b^2+c^2$ part?? Because that’s false (except for the equality)..

Comment: well i tried many attempts but always have that result so i dont know how do it right :<

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with an application of Jensen's inequality. You want to come up with a function $f(x)$ such that $f(a)=\frac{1}{bc+2a^2+2a}$, $f(b)=\frac{1}{ac+2b^2+2b}$, and $f(c)= \frac{1}{ab+2c^2+2c}$. Then use the second derivative to show that this function is convex which allows you to apply Jensen's inequality. Jensen's inequality will give you the left side of your inequality is less than or equal to $f(a+b+c)$ which you will then need to do some algebra to show is less than the desired $\frac{1}{ab+bc+ca}$. The fact that $a+b+c=1$ will help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Due to CS:

$$\sum \frac1{\left( ab+2c^2+2c \right)} \cdot \sum \left(a^2b^2 (ab+2c^2+2c) \right) \ge \left(\sum ab\right)^2.$$

Divide both parts by $\left(\sum ab\right)^3:$

$$\sum \frac1{\left( ab+2c^2+2c \right)}\cdot \frac{ \sum \left(a^2b^2 (ab+2c^2+2c) \right)}{\left(\sum ab\right)^3} \ge \frac1{\sum ab}.$$

It is enough to prove that $$\frac{ \sum \left(a^2b^2 (ab+2c^2+2c) \right)}{\left(\sum ab\right)^3}\le 1.$$

Rewrite as:

$$\sum (ab)^3+\sum 2(a^2b^2c^2+a^2b^2c) \le \sum (ab)^3+\sum 3(a^3b^2c+a^3bc^2)+6a^2b^2c^2.$$

Since $a+b+c=1$:

$$\sum 2a^2b^2c(a+b+c) \le \sum 3(a^3b^2c+a^3bc^2).$$

Or: $$6a^2b^2c^2 \le \sum (a^3b^2c+ab^2c^3),$$

which is true due to sum of three AM-GMs.